Vs code title bar color changing automatically
Whenever i open my vs code title bar or activity bar color changing automatically
It starts happening when i installed peacock extension (used to change color for different vs code window) and i didn't like it so i uninstalled it.
Even after uninstalling the peacock extension it changes color of title bar every single time when i open the vs code
"by creating .vscode folder in the project folder and in that folder settings.json file is created which contains the code to change color of title bar"
This images shows the settings.json file and color changed in vs code activity bar:

how to stop the .vscode folder which is created automatically?

try reinstalling VS Code?

Already tried that doesn't work

Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled command in the command palette)? If not, then do an extension bisect to figure out what extension is causing it.
